# how to use print when condition in jasper table

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to dynamically show or hide   my table footer in jasper  Report  I edited my print when condition  but it shows some error . can someone please help me. I will attach my screen shots[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I remember, you can use only parameters in Table's conditions

Comment: You need to post your jrxml and the error message as text, screen shot is not good for SO, your post can not be indexed.

Comment: The variable you have created is inside sub dataset not in the main dataset. And the print when expression only check the main dataset values (parameter, field , variable.)

Answer (score 2):

As I said you have created a variable in the sub data set which is not recognizable by the print when expression. 
Do this in order to hide this:

- Remove the print when expression condition leave it as blank.
- Apply below snippet to each text field that you are going to use in table footer

Like lets say there are three text field in your table footer, then each text field should contain condition 
`$V{variable_name} == null ? null : "something you want to print."`
this should not written print when expression.

- Important: Set all text field property `Blank when null`
- `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` add this to `reportElement` tag. This tag is associated with each of your text field. so find correct `reportElement` tag and paste it.

Now execute your `jrxml`. It will show and hide if there is data in your variable.